# vs code jest extension не запускает отдельные тесты

Tags: create-react-app, jest

При нажатии на зелёную галочку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По testMatch видно что тесты находятся, а по Pattern нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте код (который можно запустить) текстом, также как и получаемые результаты.

Comment: Код тут не важен, тесты работают через команду npm test, но не работают через плагин jest для vs code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ, такая проблема возникает если у вас установлен npm < 8.15v, я обновил у себя и всё заработало как надо.